# Calculate the percentile cutoffs for each country and grouping on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I want create new column "Classification" with three values filled.
e.g.
Country - Colombia -25 URL (Ranking ascending)

1. Top 20% - 5 (first 5 indexes to be included here)
2. Next 12% - 2(round off)(next 2 indexes to be included here)
3. Bottom 68% - 18 (remaining 18 indexes to be included here)
   similarly with each country.

Here in my code, I'm finding row count of each country data and then using quantile to get index values so that I can slice data in these three categories.

Working with Columns: "URL" , "Country" and "Ranking".

```py
data = data.groupby(['Country', 'URL'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Ranking'], ascending=True))

# Add a new column to count the number of URLs in each country
data['URL Count'] = data.groupby('Country')['URL'].transform('count')

# Calculate percentiles based on the URL Count column
top_percentile = int(round(data['URL Count'].quantile(0.2)))
next_percentile = int(round(data['URL Count'].quantile(0.32)))

# Categorize the rows based on the percentiles
data['Classification'] = np.where(data['URL Count'] <= top_percentile, '1. Top 20%', 
                   np.where(data['URL Count'] <= next_percentile, '2. Next 12%',
                   '3. Bottom 68%'))

# Create a separate dataframe for the categorized data
categorized_data = data[['Country', 'URL', 'Ranking', 'Classification']]
```

Here is the of the data I need to work with -

| URL | Country | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| URL1 | USA | 83 |
| URL2 | China | 111 |
| URL3 | USA | 111 |
| URL4 | USA | 135 |
| URL5 | China | 135 |
| URL6 | USA | 135 |
| URL7 | USA | 139 |
| URL8 | China | 250 |
| URL9 | USA | 250 |
| URL10 | USA | 369 |
| URL11 | United Kingdom | 369 |
| URL12 | Japan | 401 |
| URL13 | USA | 401 |
| URL14 | Azerbaijan | 2664 |
| URL15 | Azerbaijan | 4473 |
| URL16 | Armenia | 10922 |
| URL17 | South Africa | 21692 |
| URL18 | South Africa | 22305 |
| URL19 | South Africa | 23137 |
| URL20 | Armenia | 981629 |
| URL21 | Argentina | 999689 |
| URL22 | Morocco | 999732 |
| URL23 | Indonesia | 999919 |
| URL24 | Netherlands | 999976 |
| URL25 | India | 99999999 |
| URL26 | France | 99999999 |
| URL27 | France | 99999999 |

Comment: Looks like you want `groupby().transform(pd.quantile)`, then you can use a `np.select` to find the category.

Comment: @QuangHoang edited my question after some research, still not getting there :(

Comment: you need to transform the `quantile` of `Ranking` not the `count`.